# Successfully setting up React Native in Visual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: react-native, setup-project

I'm having a real difficult time setting up React Native on Visual Studio Code on my mac. I have read multiple tutorials and watched youtube and Lynda videos on how to do it - follow the steps exactly as they are presented, but still it doesn't completely works. It seems like every other terminal command I run gets an error.

I have managed to get it running on my physical iPhone and in the Android emulator. But when I try get it up and running on my iOS simulator using the appropriate terminal command, it won't work. The simulator opens, but then the terminal seems to get stuck loading and the app isn't showing in the simulator. There's no error, but it doesn't run.

Another thing is that I don't seem to find the index.ios and index.android files respectively - just a single App.js file.

I guess what I'm asking for is a good thorough guid on setting it up. Most guides I come across seem to leave out or under-explain certain steps, assuming that you already understand certain concepts. Please post a link if you know any super guides :) Thanks!

Comment: open iOS app on emulator from XCode. In the latest react native projects both iOS and android files are merged into single index.js by default.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the [React Native website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)? Specifically what's under the tab **Building Projects with Native Code**. The fact that you're looking for the `index.*.js` files tells me that the tutorials you are following are all out of date as those files have been removed a while ago.

Comment: @MichaelCheng, you should be more specific here: the `index.*.js` files were replaced by a unified `index.js` file (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#the-react-native-component) which is the entry file of the whole app. 
If that is not there, obviously the app won't start up properly as there is no entry point.

Comment: @flaky Kinda assumed that if the asker read the comments in succession, they'd have understood that part. They have yet to clarify their question though so can't help further anyway.

Comment: @devedv Thanks, that's really good to know! Had no idea that the index files were merged. Things make more sense now. I'll try the tips you suggested. Fingers crossed it works :)

Comment: @devedv Did you mean that I should just start up a new Xcode project and then the simulator, then run the command `$sudo npm run ios´ ? Same thing... terminal gets stuck on line `Running app on xxxxx 7#2 in development mode` :(

Comment: Also, I don't actually have something called index.js. There is an App.js file. Is that the same thing?

Comment: You can create an empty index.js file in the root of your React Native project. But I think just to clarify stuff first Create a new folder access it from cmd and write this command create-react-native-app SampleProjec. Just browse through files in this project you will understand the react native project structure better.